# How to emberd microsoft word to asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to open Microsoft word document in asp.net web application  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QB9q.png) how do i do that on asp.net.

Comment: do you want to open Word when a user click a link or you want to embed it in your web application window as if it was running inside the browser?

Comment: 'Haitham Shaddad' yes that is exactly what i want,to embed it in my web application window as if it was running inside the browser.Is there any method for doing that in ASP.net ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Aceoffix plugin from [this link](http://www.aceoffix.com/).

and view demos of asp.net examples.

you can refresh try license every tree month.

and i use these code for open word in browser:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = null;

      //open word template:                 
 document = application.Documents.Add(Server.MapPath("Smear.docx"));

     //save word doc to folder:
 string NameReport = Server.MapPath(serial.Trim() + ".docx");
 document.SaveAs(NameReport);
 application.Quit();
```

before quit application you can edit [fields](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-fields-c429bbb0-8669-48a7-bd24-bab6ba6b06bb) text of document (for me is in header section):

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in document.Sections)
{
    document.TrackRevisions = false;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeadersFooters headers = section.Headers;
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter header in headers)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Fields fields = header.Range.Fields;    
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field field in fields)
        {    
            switch (field.Result.Text)
            {
                case "example_field1":
                    field.Result.Text = "your text";
                    break;
                case "example-field2":
                    field.Result.Text = " your text";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```